# Elastic script_score, only count specific array elements

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a bunch of objects like this one in Elastic:

```
{
          "id" : "b397ab9c-2bab-4cce-a419-ba6b23545772",
          "name": "Alice",
          // other fields omitted
          "foo" : [
            {
              "id" : "1",
              "bar" : 20
            },
            {
              "id" : "2",
              "bar" : 20
            }
           ]
},
{
          "id" : "826784cb-7dcd-4d2c-b444-a466032a7b06",
          "name": "Bob",
          // other fields omitted
          "foo" : [
            {
              "id" : "1",
              "bar" : 15
            }
           ]
}
```

I am trying to make a score based on any elements in `foo` of which the `id` is `2`. So in the above objects, Alice has a score of 20 and Bob has a score of 0 (as there's no element with id `2` in his `foo` array. I'm however a bit stuck in how to have my script_score look for the specific element. Here is my query:

```
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "score_mode": "max", 
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "foo.id": {
                "value": "2"
              }
            }
          },
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['foo'].values /* what goes here? */",
              "params": {
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is foo nested ?

Comment: No, the foo key is in the root of the object. It is an array that contains simple objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `foo` is not of type `nested`, you'll have lost the connection between `id` and `bar` due to [value flattenning](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-arrays-flattening-objects).

After you've reconfigured your mapping to be `nested`, you can do

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "foo",
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "score_mode": "max",
          "functions": [
            {
              "script_score": {
                "script": {
                  "source": "if (doc['foo.id.keyword'].value == '2') { def bar = doc['foo.bar'].value; return bar } return 0",
                  "params": {}
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but without the `filter` because that'd have filtered out doc#2 since it does not meet that condition and you probably want to do some sort of a scripted fallback.

Do note that once you're in the `nested` context, you don't have access to other object groups in your `foo` array. In other words, when you're in `id: 2`, you don't *see* the `id: 1` group. More info [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/help-for-painless-iterate-nested-fields/162394/4).

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'll try reconfiguring my mapping tomorrow.

Comment: Got it working, thanks. I'll buy you a coffee tonight!

Comment: coming here from the other question posted by @yesman and answered by joe

im just here because i actually found a nice interaction in the comments

Comment: Cheers @Alvaromon! Which question though?