# Elastic search apply boost based on nested field value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-7

Below is my indexed document

```
 {
  "defaultBoostValue":1.01,
  "boostDetails": [
    {
      "Type": "Type1",
      "value": 1.0001
    },
    {
      "Type": "Type2",
      "value": 1.002
    },
    {
      "Type": "Type3",
      "value": 1.0005
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to apply boost based on value passed, so suppose i pass Type 1 then boost applied will be 1.0001 and if that Type1 does not exist then it will use defaultBoostValue
below is my query which works but quite slow, is there any way to optimize it further

[Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65688013/elastic-search-filter-based-on-array-of-object)
Above query works but is slow as we are using _source

```
   {
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "boost_mode": "multiply",
      "functions": [
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": """
                double findBoost(Map params_copy) {
                    for (def group : params_copy._source.boostDetails) {
                        if (group['Type'] == params_copy.preferredBoostType ) {
                            return group['value'];
                        }
                    }
                    return params_copy._source['defaultBoostValue'];
                }
                
                return findBoost(params)
              """,
              "params": {
                "preferredBoostType": "Type1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have removed the condition of not having dynamic mapping, if changing the structure of boostDetails mapping can help then I am ok but please explain how it can help and be faster to query also please give mapping types and modified structure if answer contains modifying mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using dynamic mappings (lots of fields)

It looks like you adjusted the doc structure compared to [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65688013/8160318).

The query above was thought for nested fields which cannot be *easily* iterated in a script for performance reasons. Having said that, the above is an even slower workaround which accesses the docs' `_source` and iterates its contents. But keep in mind that it's **not recommended** to access the `_source` in scripts!

If your docs aren't nested anymore, you can access the so-called [doc values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html) which are much more optimized for query-time access:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      ...
      "functions": [
        {
          ...
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "lang": "painless",
              "source": """
                try {
                  if (doc['boost.boostType.keyword'].value == params.preferredBoostType) {
                    return doc['boost.boostFactor'].value;
                  } else {
                    throw new Exception();
                  }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                  return doc['fallbackBoostFactor'].value;
                }
              """,
              "params": {
                "preferredBoostType": "Type1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

thus speeding up your function score query.

---

#### Alternative using an ordered list of values

Since the nested iteration is slow and dynamic mappings are blowing up your index, you could store your boosts in a standardized ordered list in each document:

```
"boostValues": [1.0001, 1.002, 1.0005, ..., 1.1]
```

and keep track of the corresponding boost types' order in the backend where you construct the queries:

```
var boostTypes = ["Type1", "Type2", "Type3", ..., "TypeN"]
```

So something like [n-hot vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot).

Then, as you construct the Elasticsearch query, you'd look up the **array index** of the `boostValues` based on the `boostType` and pass this array index to the script query from above which'd access the corresponding `boostValues` doc-value.

This is guaranteed to be faster than `_source` access. **But it's required that you always keep your `boostTypes` and `boostValues` in sync** -- preferably append-only (as you add new `boostTypes`, the list grows in one dimension).

Comment: thanks, so above will work if indexed structure is like {boost: {"Type1": 1.00003},  {Type2: 1.222}} right ?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: this will require to have dynamic index, i was looking for solution without dynamic index.

Comment: i have edited the question to match original question and also added link to original question

Comment: How many types will you have? Is it known?

Comment: yeah it is known but then again number of possible types are many approx 200

Comment: OK but it's known and doesn't change too often?

Comment: it can change as it comes from big query and other data source

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer w/ an alternative. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: @AkashSalunkhe do these vectors sound feasible?

Comment: No, it does not, as it is not possible to modify vector on realtime basis, i have removed the condition for not having dynamic query, if modifying the index can help to write better query then i am ok with it

Comment: OK. ~200 separate boost fields aren't too bad.